# Problem with mapping codes to county names in Python | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataset containing almost 400 counties from Poland. I need to merge several files containing data related to these counties. Each county is identified by its name and a code. However, there's a challenge: there are 10 pairs of counties with the same name. For example, there is a county called 'powiat brzeski' in both the Małopolskie and Opolskie provinces. To differentiate between these counties, I want to add the name of the province next to the county name using Python. I attempted to do this with the below method, but encountered an issue: after the manipulation, the values in the 'County' column, except for those affected by the manipulation, turned into NaN. Could you assist me with resolving this issue?

```
  import pandas as pd

  # Sample DataFrame
data = {'Code': [1202000, 2402000, 802000, 3017000, 3005000, 9999999], # Added an unmatched code 9999999
        'County': ['Powiat brzeski', 'Powiat bielski', 'Powiat krośnieński', 'Powiat ostrowski', 'Powiat grodziski', 'Powiat ciechanowski']} # Added an unmatched county
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

 
# Print updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

Result:

```
     Code               County
0  1202000       Powiat brzeski
1  2402000       Powiat bielski
2   802000   Powiat krośnieński
3  3017000     Powiat ostrowski
4  3005000     Powiat grodziski
5  9999999  Powiat ciechanowski


data = {'Code': [1202000, 2402000, 802000, 3017000, 3005000, 9999999], # Added an unmatched code 9999999
        'County': ['Powiat brzeski', 'Powiat bielski', 'Powiat krośnieński', 'Powiat ostrowski', 'Powiat grodziski', 'Powiat ciechanowski']} # Added an unmatched county
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Dictionary mapping codes to county names
code_to_county = {
    1202000: "Powiat brzeski_Malopolskie",
    2402000: "Powiat bielski_Slaskie",
    802000: "Powiat krośnieński_Lubuskie",
    3017000: "Powiat ostrowski_Wielkopolskie",
    3005000: "Powiat grodziski_Wielkopolskie"
}

# Update values in "County" column based on values in "Code" column
df['County'] = df['Code'].map(code_to_county)

# Print updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      Code                          County
0  1202000      Powiat brzeski_Malopolskie
1  2402000          Powiat bielski_Slaskie
2   802000     Powiat krośnieński_Lubuskie
3  3017000  Powiat ostrowski_Wielkopolskie
4  3005000  Powiat grodziski_Wielkopolskie
5  9999999                             NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
In [79]: df['County'] = df['Code'].map(code_to_county).combine_first(df['County'])

In [80]: df
Out[80]: 
      Code                          County
0  1202000      Powiat brzeski_Malopolskie
1  2402000          Powiat bielski_Slaskie
2   802000     Powiat krośnieński_Lubuskie
3  3017000  Powiat ostrowski_Wielkopolskie
4  3005000  Powiat grodziski_Wielkopolskie
5  9999999             Powiat ciechanowski
```